# REST in workflow applications - where to keep the state?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, workflow

I tried to take a more detailed look at REST - Spring seems to love it so much, and I am confused. REST is fine for basic CRUD operations on "resources", but it seems awkward for applications which need to keep state, such as workflow applications. I read in one of the answers on SO, can't find it now, that the state should be kept on the client. This seems strange: what prevents then the client from cooking up a request, claiming he is in a state which he is not in? A way around this could be that the server sends to the client his next state signed, and the client then uses this signed state on his next request to the server. If anyone has seen a "RESTful workflow application", is this how things actually get done?

Comment: doesn't the RestBucks sample app have some state and workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST = Representational **STATE** Transfer. Client and server exchange the state of a resource. So basically it's kept on the server and updated (/created/deleted) by the client.

REST isn't awkward at all for workflow applications, however you may define that. The most difficult part when designing REST applications is designing the representations and most of all the resources. A resource isn't merely an entity from the database.

As @NeilMcGuigan has mentioned, the RestBucks sample application deals with workflows. There's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3rP4VT7qWM) on the SpringSourceDev Channel on YouTube, where Oliver Gierke presents the application.

Comment: sorry if I did not understand correctly, but application state is not necessarily the set of states of domain objects; for example in workflow applications where the workflow is represented as a BPMN diagram or as a BPEL process. Would you suggest in this case to see the application state itself as a "resource"?

Comment: Imagine an airline. You have a resource like flight ticket. Behind the ordering process is a complex workflow. The client of the service is only interested in the flight ticket, not any application state. The client orders, consumes  or cancels the ticket by manipulating the resource accordingly. What happens behind the scenes - the workflow - is completely opaque to the client. In case the order was refused the client, of course, can neither consume nor cancel the ticket.